# Excel VBA WebQuery Import From Google Sheet some values ​are not taken

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets

I Found this VBA code from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYXf6vyomCk,
Iam trying to import data from Google Sheets into Excel but one or more values are not retrieved if surrounding cells contain different types (number/text), what's wrong, is there any solution?
Here's [a link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_27rjNQmlXrwVKpLWUbGrJYPJufGRa7Dk-XEKcNAHr0/edit#gid=1628955556)! in google sheet and result in excel (https://drive.google.com/file/d/13eKELcqoeOKltAYYjes-j-lLMQrgyFwH/view?usp=sharing)!

```
Sub QueryGoogleSheets()
      Dim qt As QueryTable, url As String, key As String, gid As String
 
      If ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Count > 0 Then ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1).Delete
      ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear
 
      key = "1_27rjNQmlXrwVKpLWUbGrJYPJufGRa7Dk-XEKcNAHr0"
      gid = "1628955556"
      url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tqx=out:html&key=" & key _
      & "&gid=" & gid
 
       
      Set qt = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & url, _
      Destination:=Range("a1"))
 
      With qt
          .WebSelectionType = xlAllTables
          .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
          .Refresh
      End With
  End Sub
```

---

To reproduce the problem run the code above and it will populate the Excel Sheet, however if you compare the data in the Sheet to the webpage its not retrieving all the information:

https://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?tqx=out:html&key=1_27rjNQmlXrwVKpLWUbGrJYPJufGRa7Dk-XEKcNAHr0&gid=1628955556

Comment: why can't all values ​​be retrieved? how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Select the data and click the Left Format button, I checked and the data is the same as the website:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/d/1_27rjNQmlXrwVKpLWUbGrJYPJufGRa7Dk-XEKcNAHr0/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&gid=1628955556

[image]

The column L is fine:

[image]

Comment: it should be in column L in the second row the text "fgufucfhxdh" but in excel it's empty, check [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_27rjNQmlXrwVKpLWUbGrJYPJufGRa7Dk-XEKcNAHr0/edit#gid=1628955556)

Comment: [edit] your question to show me, I've attached a second screenshot.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've edited

Comment: However, if the column L of the second row is filled with numbers, the value can be taken